# In VHDL is there a way using std_texio to read elements of a .csv file and store them in a variable to then use?

Tags: csv, vhdl

I can currently use the readline and read function to read a line from the file and store the characters in variables governed by the size of the variable im putting them into for example if the first line of the file was

hello,world

and I wanted to store the two words in different variables I would do something along the lines of

```
file      in_file         :  text open READ_MODE  is "hello_world.csv";
variable  in_line         :  line;
variable  first_word      :  string(1to5);
variable  second_word     :  string(1to5);

begin
readline(infile,inline);
read(inline,first_word);
read(inline,second_word);
```

however that is dependent upon the size of the elements I want to be able to generically read the first element before the comma and assign that to a variable then look for the next element until the next comma and store that in a different variable if that makes sense.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The open source [VUnit test framework](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit) has a standalone [string operations package](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit/tree/master/vhdl/string_ops) containing a split function

```
impure function split (
  constant s         : string;
  constant sep       : string;
  constant max_split : integer := -1)
 return lines_t;
```

that you can use to split a string (`s`) into its parts which are separated by `sep`. For example

```
parts := split("hello,world",",");
```

`parts` is a vector of elements of type `line` so `parts[0].all` would in this case equal `hello`. Have a look at the [testbench](https://github.com/LarsAsplund/vunit/blob/master/vhdl/string_ops/test/tb_string_ops.vhd) for the package and look for the "Test split" test case to see the details on how the function handles various normal inputs and corner cases.

Since we use the `line` type rather than `string` we don't have to know the length of individual elements.

I'm one of the authors for VUnit.